# Nested ServiceStack Sites & Routes

Tags: iis-7, iis-express, servicestack

I have a large number of services that my team are building and the auto-generated metadata is getting a bit unmanageable.  To combat this, I created a project as a nested site (or sub-site) of the root.  This works fine on my IIS local, but doesn't seem to work on a server-based IIS.  Is it possible to get URLs like the following:

```
 - http://server/WebServices  [Root Project]
 - http://server/WebServices/Project1  [Sub Project 1]
 - http://server/WebServices/Project2  [Sub Project 2]
```

I know that using the routes in the AppHost I can get this effect but the resulting metadata is starting to get huge as they're all in one site.  What I want is to be able to manage separate services in separate projects and have them come out in a hierarchy similar to above.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the implementation of [Routes.AddFromAssembly()](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/ServiceRoutesExtensions.cs#L26) extension method which goes through all the services are registers routes with the following conventions:

```
/{requestDto}
/{requestDto}/{Id}
```

On each of the HTTP Verbs that are implemented.

You should be able to implement your own conventions using a similar approach.